# How to tell the Coq kernel that a parameter of a lambda function is a subterm of another variable in the scope?

Tags: list, recursion, coq, termination, foldleft

I'm stuck while trying to define a recursive function in Coq over a particular type of n-ary tree.

The n-ary tree type I'm using is defined as a mutually inductive type as follows:

```
Inductive tree : Type :=
| leaf : tree
| node : childs -> tree
with childs : Type :=
| childs_one : tree -> childs
| childs_cons : tree -> childs -> childs.
```

Note that a node has at least one child. If I want to check that a given Boolean property is verified over all the nodes in a tree, I can write a mutually recursive function to go through the whole structure. However, since the `childs` type is close to the `list tree` type, and since the standard library offers a lot of lemmas about lists, I want to convert an instance of the `childs` type into a list and use the `fold_left` function to do the computation. The function I want to write is as follows :

```
Fixpoint check_nodes (chk : tree -> bool) (t : tree) {struct t} : bool := 
  match t with
  | leaf => chk t
  | node chs => fold_left (fun b ti => b && check_nodes chk ti) (childs2list chs) true
  end.
```

Here, the `childs2list` function is a trivial function that converts an instance of the `childs` type into of list of `tree`. The `check_nodes` function does not type-check because the Coq kernel is not able to determine that the `ti` parameter of the lambda function passed to `fold_left` is a subterm of `t`.

I haven't yet managed to find a workaround for this problem. I really want to use the `fold_left` function for lists in the definition of my function. My attempts to define the function with the `Fix` combinator, and a well-founded relation (based on a "number of nodes" measure) were not successful.

Does anyone have a solution? Or, must I forget about using the `fold_left` function?

Here is a complete  minimal example:

```
Require Import Bool.
Require Import List.
Import ListNotations.

Inductive tree : Type :=
| leaf : tree
| node : childs -> tree
with childs : Type :=
| childs_nil : childs
| childs_cons : tree -> childs -> childs.

Fixpoint childs2list (chs : childs) {struct chs} : list tree :=
  match chs with
  | childs_nil => nil
  | childs_cons t chs' => t :: childs2list chs'
  end.

Fixpoint check_nodes (chk : tree -> bool) (t : tree) {struct t} : bool := 
  match t with
  | leaf => chk t
  | node chs => fold_left (fun b t__i => b && check_nodes chk t__i) (childs2list chs) true
  end.
```

Many thanks for taking the time to read my question,

Vincent.

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid there isn't a clean way of achieving exactly what you want. One possibility would be to use a nested `list` instead of a mutual inductive, and keep the last child as a separate parameter of `node`. For example:

```
Require Import Bool.
Require Import List.
Import ListNotations.

Inductive tree :=
| leaf
| node (first : list tree) (last : tree).

Fixpoint check_nodes (chk : tree -> bool) (t : tree) {struct t} : bool :=
  match t with
  | leaf => chk t
  | node first last =>
      fold_left (fun b ti => b && check_nodes chk ti) first (check_nodes chk last)
  end.
```

Or, if you want to use `forallb` instead,

```
Fixpoint check_nodes (chk : tree -> bool) (t : tree) {struct t} : bool :=
  match t with
  | leaf => chk t
  | node first last => forallb (check_nodes chk) first && check_nodes chk last
  end.
```

Comment: I agree with Arthur: once you re-construct a new piece of data, the guard checker cannot keep track of the information that all subterms of this new structure are indeed subterms of the initial argument.

Comment: Thank you for your answers! I was looking for a solution that would not imply the transformation of the data structure. But I guess there is no way around it...